Sign In With Apple with a backend - flow is unclear
I'm building an app that supports sign in with Apple. The user authenticates on the front end following the approach Apple describes here. After the user signs in, I send their identityToken to the backend to verify it, using Apple's public key for verifying the token signature. At this point if the user's token checks out, I issue them a login token into my own application that the client can then use for authenticating further requests.
I'm unsure how to proceed with regards to the Apple login. The Apple documentation seems to describe two possibly relevant flows--one for mobile Sign In With Apple, which doesn't involve any communication with the server, and one for REST Sign in with Apple. I can't tell whether only my app needs to be the one verifying whether the user should still be logged in, or whether I should be doing it through my server, getting refresh tokens, etc.
